# How should i access specific data from large JSON file using a search button?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js, force-layout

My final goal is to create a Force-layout using `d3` , where I have a search `ui-widget` similar to this :

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="search">
    <button type="button" onclick="searchNode()">Search</button>
</div>
```

I want to search a node using that `ui-widget` , and when it finds it I want to display only the node with all the links and nodes linked to it .
The problem is that I have multiple groups of nodes and links in the big JSON file I linked down. I don't know how I should load all of them. Here are some options I have in mind:

1. Create somehow a hashmap with the key/value -> name/all the content of the JSON and push it in an array. When I search using that search button I will look just for the key and display the value .
2. Reformat the JSON to have all the nodes and after all the links, in 2 big chunks, not like I have them now node/link , node ,link .

I have this large JSON containing many JSON's

**JSON.json**

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Source","label":"source","group": 0},
    {"id": "Parent_1","label":"name6","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_2","label":"name5","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_3","label":"name4","group": 1},
    {"id": "Child_1","label":"name3","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_2","label":"name2","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_3","label":"name1","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_4","label":"name0", "group": 3}
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_3"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_3"},
    { "source": "Child_2","target": "Child_4"}
  ]
}
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Source","label":"source","group": 0},
    {"id": "Parent_12","label":"name6","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_22","label":"name5","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_32","label":"name4","group": 1},
    {"id": "Child_12","label":"name3","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_22","label":"name2","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_32","label":"name1","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_42","label":"name0", "group": 3}
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_12"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_22"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_32"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_12"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_22"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_32"},
    { "source": "Child_22","target": "Child_42"}
  ]
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  font: 9px helvetica;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("JSON.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.label })
      .style("stroke", "gray");
  node.on("click", function() {
      alert(function(d){return d.Statement})
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });

 node.on('mouseover', function(d){
    var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.8'});
    nodeSelection.select("text").style({opacity:'1.0'});
})


  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

What i want is similar to this , except all my nodes are saved in a different file : http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/Bf5nM/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Bf5nM

If the question is unclear please tell me so i can edit , thank you .

I parsed multiple files and the result is a large JSON file . In that JSON file i have groups of nodes and links as you can see , and i want to represent one group at a time .

Comment: What are you searching for precisely? The id, label or group?

Comment: @clabe45 i search by id , the id with the label can be identical it doesn't matter

Comment: Can you elaborate more? You have multiple json files?

Comment: @clabe45 yes , i will edit it right now , there are not multiple json files , it is just one large file , i was thinking on creating more json files for each group but the original (not this example) file has 70.000 code lines + so it wouldn't be so good .

Comment: "i want to represent one group at a time" ... so you want to search each group all together?

Comment: @clabe45 Yes , i want to store all the groups in an array and when i search for one group i want to display just that single group .Like array[0] = nodes/links for the first group , array[1]= nodes/links for the second group and so on .

Comment: "What have you tried"?

Comment: @clabe45 That's the thing i didn't , i have no idea how it is better to approach the problem . I am a newbie in js and d3 . I am thinking to push each group in an array . That's the best i got for the moment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put them all into one array, if you want to search them separately. I'm not familiar with d3, but wouldn't a simple for loop like this do the trick; where `currentObject` is the chunk of JSON you want to search:

```
var searchedId = document.getElementById("search").value;
for (var i=0; i<currentObject.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = currentObject.nodes[i];
    if (node.id == searchedId) {
        // display node
    }
}
```